# SCSI drives not showing up in Linux CentOS 4

Tags: linux, centos, raid, dell, scsi

So I have a poweredge 6650 with Perc 3 installed. on the first channel of raid controller I have 2x 73gb configured in raid 1. On the second channel I have two 300GB drives that are stand alone.

The two 300gb drives do not show up in linux, (no /dev/sdb*)...

Can perc 3 support non-raid and raid drives combined?
Is there any settings I may be missing?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the Dell management software, or the BIOS, to configure the 300Gb disk as a single JBOD VDISK.

Answer (score 0):

is the second channel connected to the backplane at all? is the backplane split to support two channels?

easy to check - go into the controller BIOS and look for the 300Gb drives. If they don't show up - Linux has nothing to do with it.

Comment: The PERC card doesn't pass through unconfigured disks; they don't have to be in an array, but it has to be told to pass them through.

Comment: true, for standalone, they have to be set up in a raid0 single disk VD